# how to pass a value to an other dialog component in angular

Tags: angular

I have a component that I used it as a dialog on my main component, It works but I have to know how to send to it a value (an object) to insert it values on my form when the user fires the dialog (and If the object = null it makes the form clear);

here is my component

1- the main component:

```
export class GestionDesChauffeursComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private _fuseTranslationLoaderService: FuseTranslationLoaderService,
    private service: GetionChauffeursService, private dialog: MatDialog) { this._fuseTranslationLoaderService.loadTranslations(english, turkish); }
  Update_chauffeur(){
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.height = "570px";
    dialogConfig.width = "550px";
    this.dialog.open(EditNewChauffeursComponent,dialogConfig);
  }
  onEdit(row){
const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
dialogConfig.disableClose = false;
dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
dialogConfig.height = "570px";
dialogConfig.width = "550px";
//this.dialog.open(EditNewChauffeursComponent,dialogConfig);
this.dialog.open(EditNewChauffeursComponent,{
  ...dialogConfig,
  data: {
     // data I want to pass into the dialog
     myVar: row
  }


});


 onDelete(key){
    var index = index = this.listDriverElementEntity.map(x => {return x.key}).indexOf(key);
    console.log(index);
    this.listDriverElementEntity.splice(index, 1);
    this.service.Removechauffeur(key).subscribe(data=>{
    this.listdata = new MatTableDataSource(this.listDriverElementEntity);
    console.log(data);
    });

  }
```

Rq: The row contains the object of my datatable is the object what I will send when I fire the onEdit function.

My EditNewChauffeursComponent comoponet:

```
model: any = {};
  profileForm = this.fb.group({
    Nom_de_famille: ['', Validators.required],
    Prénom: ['', Validators.required],
    email: ['', [Validators.email,Validators.required]],
    Code_personnel: ['', Validators.required],
    N_tel: [''],
    Département: ['', Validators.required]
  });
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditNewChauffeursComponent>, private fb: FormBuilder,private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,private service: GetionChauffeursService) { }


 @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) indata: any 
    ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.indata);
    }
      setdefaultformvalues(row) {
        this.profileForm.setValue({
          Nom_de_famille: [row.FirstName],
          Prénom: [row.LastName],
          email: [row.Email],
          Code_personnel: [row.DriverCode],
          N_tel: [''],
          Département: ['']
        });
      }
```

I just changes my code But 'indata' gives undefined value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you open the dialog you can pass data :

for example:

```js
    // instead of : 
    this.dialog.open(EditNewChauffeursComponent,dialogConfig);

    // you can do : 
    this.dialog.open(EditNewChauffeursComponent,{
       ...dialogConfig,
       data: {
          // data I want to pass into the dialog
          myVar: 'my var val'
       }
    });
```

on the modal side you will have to add an injector to receive the data, here's how :

```js
 // ... my code 

 constructor(

    // add the following to your constructor : 
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) indata: any ) { }


    // you can use the injected variable as you would any other 
    // injected var, meaning something like: 
    ngOnInit() {
       this.setdefaultformvalues(this.indata);//will have row objct
    }
```

Comment: when I put that piece of code `    this.dialog.open(EditNewChauffeursComponent,dialogConfig, {
      data: {
         myVar: row
      }
   });`
I got an error on (property) myVar: any

Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.ts(2554)

Comment: I just updated my answer, I missed the fact that you already had dialogConfig in place. you just need to add dialogConfig.data = { ... your code }, or anwrap dialogConfig as I've done in my edit above

Comment: Plz see My changes on qst

Comment: ` @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) indata: any ` should be inside the constructor. just like `private fb: FormBuilder`

Comment: ok now Property 'indata' does not exist on type 'EditNewChauffeursComponent'.ts

Comment: if you added that snippet to your constructor it will be available throughout your class by using `this.indata`. If you are getting errors that it's undefined or does not exist it means that you missed a step, and I encourage you to go back and read my answer.  If you are trying to access it from your HTML or an inherited component and getting that error, you should probably consider making indata `protected` or `public` instead of `private`